# Is it possible to boot Linux from an external or internal hard drive?

Tags: unix, boot

My company wish to boot Linux/Unix images from an external or internal hard drive. Can it be done by making the hard drive bootable, similar to booting Windows 7 from a pen drive?

If so, how can I do this?

Comment: Internal hard disk? Aren't that your regular hard disks? I'd have another look at what you're really asking for. Furthermore, you should focus on the *how* rather than *if* its possible.

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible. USB, HDD even a memory card. Here is a [guide](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/linux/create-a-bootable-ubuntu-usb-flash-drive-the-easy-way/).

Comment: If its an internal hard disk, you simply have to press the defined button when you boot to bring up the BIOS boot device menu (normally F12 or one of the other F keys), and select applicable HDD. Modern motherboards might also be able to do this with HDDs attached via USB.

Comment: @xciter thx for the link ya..i will try it tomorrow with the hard disk in the office

Comment: @xciter another question, i found out the link do not have the linux/unix platform that i looking for, sorry that i do not state it precisely, the unix platform is `Zentyal`..is it possible to do so??

Comment: I do not see a reason why it wouldn't work. Get the ISO file, write the usb with it instead the ubuntu ISO file and all should be fine.

Comment: @xciter ok, i got the same thinking as you, will get it done tomorrow, thanks a lot ya. Go to bed soon.

Comment: Glad I could help.

Comment: @xciter i try just now the way but the UNetbootin unable to detect my external hard disk as my hard dish is in hard drive category instead of USB Drive. Itry to format the hard disk as FAT and NTFS, it still fail. So, any suggestion on this??

Comment: Hm, there might be an option into the bios, to change the default behavior of any usb storage device. Consult you motherboard manual.

Comment: @xciter ok, try to. But just now i use to create the bootable hard disk using own internal hard disk with window XP and result in Dual-Boot when start up. I think this can be also one way as that time i do not think of whether is it able to change the usb device behavior. Thank you for your help.